# Need help using await or promises with two functions

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

Hi have created two functions one for reading in words from a file and another for putting those words into a select component. The problem i believe is that the one is executing asynchronously but i have no idea where to put my promises or my awaits.

I have read articles on these concepts but none of them seem to apply to my example so any assistance would be much appreciated.

My first function that calls the async function.

```
  <script>

                            function readinfiles()
                            {

                                    var options = "<option value ='0'>select</option>";
                                    alert("hi");
                                    var values= getTxt();
                                    alert(values);


                            }

                    </script>
```

my second functio0n that fetches the info

```
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
                    <script>
                    getTxt =  function (){

                      $.ajax({
                            url:'fileslist.txt',
                            success: function (data){
                            return data.split('\n');
                            }
                      });
                    }
                    </script>
```

At the moment the values array is undefined and any help in restructuring these functions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First I'd recommend merging these two functions into one and prefix it with the **async** keyword. This way you can use a **promise** inside, which actually tries to get the data via ajax. Such a promise can either be rejected or resolved. If it's resolved - in your case if it successfully loaded the fileslist - instead of returning the data you can resolve the promise with the data.

Here's some code:

```
async function readinfiles() {

  var options = "<option value ='0'>select</option>";
  alert("hi");
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'fileslist.txt',
      success: function(data) {
        resolve(data.split('\n'));

      }
    });
  });

  var values = await promise;
  alert(values);
}
readinfiles();
```

To clarify, the magic is happening here:

```
  var values = await promise;
  alert(values);
```

As you can see we're creating a new variable called values and assigning it the result of the promise indicated by the **await** keyword. That means it won't execute the next function - alert() - before the promise either is resolved or rejected.

Comment: You are my hero everyone else has just been mean to me nut you've actually provided me with helpful info. Thank you very much i appreciate the help

Comment: No problem - glad I could help! =)